# Create a dynamic number of web workers Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am working on a performance heavy app, where the workload can easily be subdivided into web workers.

However because of different consumer hardware I won't know the optimal number of workers until runtime. At runtime I can find the optimal number using [navigator.hardwareConcurrency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency).

**My problem is** I can't think of a way to spawn an unknown number of workers. If I wanted to spawn 3 web workers for example I could do this:

```
var worker0 = new Worker("workerScript.js");
var worker1 = new Worker("workerScript.js");
var worker2 = new Worker("workerScript.js");
```

Is there a way to spawn and listen for events from "x" number of workers?

Comment: Did you try writing a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency)

```
let workerList = [];

for (let i = 0; i < window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency; i++) {
  let newWorker = {
    worker: new Worker('cpuworker.js'),
    inUse: false
  };
  workerList.push(newWorker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but recently I was struggling with similar problem and I wrote a small utility to execute functions in runtime on worker thread. [here](https://github.com/lokeshpathrabe/worker-util) might help